# YouTube embedded video height shorter in IE9 only

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, internet-explorer-9

I'm embedding a playlist in a Worpdress site: http://buenosairesmusica.com/videos/

It works great in all browsers except IE9. It even looks fine in IE7, 8 and 10. But in IE9 the video doesn't fill up the iframe and becomes this very narrow thing, just as wide as requested, but not tall enough in proportion.

I've tried using absolute width and height for the iframe, as well as the current option where there is an absolute width and height in the parent div and the iframe is set to width and height of 100%. Nothing works.

In case it matters, I'm on IE10 64-bit, using IE9 browser and document mode.

Answer (score 0):

In Iframe src there "v" is coming in youtube URL you have to change this "v" to "embed"

May be it works...